# how to turn two sqlite tables into a JSON object

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to turn a two table(relational tabel) from sqlite in to a JSON object? I've googling but still cannot find a way to convert those table. So far, i've only manage to turn one table into JSON object. If it's possible, can you tell me how to do it? if it's not, can you give me an alternatives? thanks.

here's the code that turn one table to JSON object:

```
private JSONArray getResults()
{
    Context context = this;

    String myPath = String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("ekantin1.db"));// Set path to database

    String myTable = DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TABLE_NAME;//Set name of table

    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null );

    JSONArray resultSet     = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
        {
            if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i) );
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                    }
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString() );


    Intent pass_data = new Intent(this,BluetoothOut.class);

    pass_data.putExtra("pindah",resultSet.toString());
    startActivity(pass_data);

    return resultSet;
}
}
```

And this is my table in my DatabaseHelper :

```
//tabel order
public static final String ORDER_TABLE_NAME="tb_order";
public static final String COL_1="ORDERID";
public static final String COL_2="USERID";
public static final String COL_3="PASSWORD";
public static final String COL_4="MEJA";
public static final String COL_5="TOPUP";
public static final String COL_6="SALDO";

//tabel lineitems
public static final String LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME="tb_lineitems";
public static final String COL1 = "FOODID";
public static final String COL2 = "PRICE";
public static final String COL3 = "NUM";
public static final String COL4 = "RES";
public static final String COL6 = "ORDERID_FK";
```

table line items and orderid related to each other where orderid in tb_order as PK and orderid_fk in tb_lineitems as FK.

Comment: Are you able to get an `Object` out of your database? As in, do you have a Class that already handles that? If so, then there is a pretty easy solution for that.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand. Did you mean a class where i pass the object to be used? @Advice-Dog

Comment: You have a database that contains rows of data, such as a `line item`. Do you have Classes that are associated with those? For getting when you're doing queries to get that information out. `LineItem myLineItem = database.getLineItemById( 35 );`

Comment: yes, i do have those @Advice-Dog

Answer (score 0):

A good way to export data from your database is to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), which is Google's Json serialization/deserialization library.

Fetch your `Objects` from your database like normally, and then use `Gson` to convert it into Json and export it.

Here is an example of how you could do it.

```
private void exportDatabase() {

    // Create an instance of Gson.
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // You can easily convert Objects into Json.
    MyItem item = new MyItem();
    String json = gson.toJson(item);



    // Fetch your items from your database.
    ArrayList<MyItems> items = database.getAll();

    // Arrays are a bit harder to convert, but not very.
    json = gson.toJson(items, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyItems>>(){}.getType());

    // Now export it to some easily copy-pasted location.
    System.out.println(json);
}
```